# solve $\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x +\sqrt{x^2+2x})$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't figure out how to mathematically solve $\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x +\sqrt{x^2+2x})$.

According to Desmos, this limit equals $-1$, and this answer was accepted by the software I'm using.

I have tried:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x +\sqrt{x^2+2x})$$

$$=\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x +\sqrt{x^2+2x}) \cdot \frac{x -\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x -\sqrt{x^2+2x}}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-2x}{x - \sqrt{x^2+2x}}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-2x}{x - x(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}})}$$

But this doesn't seem to point to $-1$ being the limit.

Comment: There are two separate questions, one in the title and one in the question body.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 My mistake, sorry!

Comment: It's OK.  Close vote retracted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem happens when you factor $x$ out of the square root. Recall that
$$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|,$$
so since $x \to -\infty$, we have $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$. Your last line should therefore be
$$=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-2x}{x + x\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}},$$
which you can see will approach $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} (x+\sqrt{x^2+2x})=\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sqrt{x^2-2x}-x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} (x\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}-x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} (x(1-\frac{1}{x}+o(\frac{1}{x^2}))-x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} (x-1+o(\frac{1}{x})-x)$$
$$=-1$$

Comment: I'm not sure what $o(\frac{1}{x^2})$ represents here. Is $o$ a variable?

Comment: That's the little-O.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Sorry, I don't know what that is.

Comment: @LuminousNutria [Little o](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html) notation describes asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: @LuminousNutria We're here to learn, so feel free to ask.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 The OP *did* ask, and you answered that $o$ is a little O. That's not the most helpful reference...

Comment: @Théophile I suppose that a key word would suffice for a Google search, and that we don't need to spoon-feed OP with a specific URL.  Nonetheless, thanks for critic.  I admit that I can make that clearer by saying "little-O notation".  I just wanted to say there's no need to apologize for not knowing anything.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} (x + \sqrt{x^2 + 2x})$

$=\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} (\frac{-2x}{x - \sqrt{x^2 + 2x}})$

$=\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} (\frac{-2}{1 - \sqrt{x^2 + 2x}/x})$

Now use $x = -\sqrt{x^2}$ when $x < 0$ to get:

$=\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} (\frac{-2}{1 + {\sqrt{1 + 2/x}}}) = -1$

Answer (score 0):

it is $$\frac{-2x}{x+x\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}$$ and this tends to $-1$ for $x$ tends to $-\infty$

Comment: Thank you, is there some way I could tell that without plugging-in multiple values for x?